# What are the Covidopoly badge requirements?

Tags: achievements, covidopoly

What are the requirements to earn the 10 badges at https://www.covidopoly.io/?

- Sound Sommelier
- Hoarder
- Taste the Rainbow
- Dr. Landlord
- Tipsy
- Partier
- Master of Surprise
- Night Owl
- Empty Handed
- Gamer

Answer (score 3):

## [Incomplete]

### Gamer (5 tiers)

1. Bronze: play 20 games (15 rolls for reward)
2. Gold: play 40 games (30 rolls for reward)
3. Platinum: play 80 games (50 rolls for reward)
4. Diamond: play 150 games (100 rolls for reward)
5. Master: play 200 games (200 rolls for reward)

### Taste the Rainbow (1 tier)

1. Bronze: win by having at least one property from each of the 10 colours (15 rolls for reward)

### Taste the Rainbow (1 tier)

1. Bronze: have one full set of properties be made completely of wildcards at the end of the game (15 rolls for reward)